# Check Existing Date object is in UTC - Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have used a Javascript function for converting date to UTC date as follows:

```
Date.prototype.convertToUTC = function () {
var month = this.getMonth();
var day = this.getDate();
var year = this.getFullYear();
return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day));
}
```

Now the problem arises when the date on which this function is applied is already in UTC. Since I don't know whether user will call this method on UTC/Local date, I want to ensure conversion happens only if it is not in UTC. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All dates have a [UTC time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) at their heart. Date objects created in a host are given a read–only [timezone offset](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26) based on the system settings, and values read using [getDate](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.14), [getHours](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.18), etc. are based on that offset.

If you want UTC milliseconds since the epoch, just use the [getTime()](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.9) method. Alternatively, there are the UTC methods, [getUTCDay](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.17), [getUTCHours](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.19), etc. to build your own formatted string.

Finally, there is [toISOString](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43) which should return an ISO formatted date string for UTC, but support may be lacking in not so old browsers.

#### Some examples

To create a local date object for 2012-11-06T15:45:01Z:

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 10, 6, 15, 45, 1));
```

To get an ISO date string from that (or any) date object:

```
var isoString = date.toISOString();
```

To get a UTC time value in milliseconds (ms since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z):

```
var timeValue = date.getTime();
```

To turn that time value back into a local date object:

```
var date = new Date(timeValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript `Date` object has the method `getTimezoneOffset()`. You could use that. Or use the `getUTC*` methods:

```
 var d = new Date();
 var utcyear = d.getUTCFullYear();
```